# How to call a variable of Google map API Javascript in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I know this is a very basic programming question but I want to have marker.position as a value of an hidden input in a form I have in HTML. I tried to use document.getElementById("position") but it is not working and I can't figure out how to do this. I would really appreciate it if someone help me with this. here are the relevant lines of the code I have:

```
function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      draggable:true,
      animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });

 var Makepoint = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     placeMarker(event.latLng); 

    google.maps.event.removeListener(Makepoint);
  });
```

and my html is

```
<input class="text" name="here" value="posit" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working with document.getElementById with his little snippet:

```
document.getElementById("hidden").value = "Your Value";
```

Of course your HTML must look like this then

```
<input id="hidden" class="text" name="here" value="posit" type="hidden" />
```

I'm just guessing that you forgot to define the ID.

Here's also a little [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AQ3P/1/) which manipulates the value of a hidden input field like you need it.

To add the position from the marker to the hidden input field you just need to do:

```
document.getElementById("hidden").value = marker.position;
```